# Find minimum value in col X in pandas DataFrame while group by col Y

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame looks like this

```
cluster_id,distance,url
0,0.1,abc.com
0,0.05,def.com
0,0.3,xyz.com
1,0.15,aaa.com
1,0.25,bbb.com
1,0.05,ccc.com
```

What I would like to do is to find minimum distance for each cluster and have a new column called centroid_url:

```
cluster_id,distance,url,centroid_url
0,0.1,abc.com,def.com
0,0.05,def.com,def.com
0,0.3,xyz.com,def.com
1,0.15,aaa.com,ccc.com
1,0.25,bbb.com,ccc.com
1,0.05,ccc.com,ccc.com
```

I can think of some ugly way to do so (for each possible cluster_id, find minimum in a for-loop), but I was wondering what is a more elegant way to do so. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [29]: df['centroid_url'] = df.loc[df.groupby('cluster_id')['distance']
                                       .transform('idxmin'), 'url'] \
                                .values

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
   cluster_id  distance      url centroid_url
0           0      0.10  abc.com      def.com
1           0      0.05  def.com      def.com
2           0      0.30  xyz.com      def.com
3           1      0.15  aaa.com      ccc.com
4           1      0.25  bbb.com      ccc.com
5           1      0.05  ccc.com      ccc.com
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['cluster_id','distance']).drop_duplicates('cluster_id')
print (df1)
   cluster_id  distance      url
1           0      0.05  def.com
5           1      0.05  ccc.com

df['centroid_url'] = df['cluster_id'].map(df1.set_index('cluster_id')['url'])
print (df)
   cluster_id  distance      url centroid_url
0           0      0.10  abc.com      def.com
1           0      0.05  def.com      def.com
2           0      0.30  xyz.com      def.com
3           1      0.15  aaa.com      ccc.com
4           1      0.25  bbb.com      ccc.com
5           1      0.05  ccc.com      ccc.com
```